# Text input as variable for array with a while loop on javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to figure out how to make a text box number reflect the number on the array i am trying to show. My code in attached. I am trying to make it that if i type "4" then 4 of my skills would pop up on my site.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function myduties1() {
var a= document.getElementById("DNumber1").value;
var duties1= ["Building Houses","Using Heavy Machinery","Lifting","Fixing","Working Fast"];
var b= a-1
var c=""
while (a>=b) {
c== "duties1[b]";
b++;
}

document.getElementById("mduties1").innerHTML =c;
}

</script>
<p><button onclick="myduties1()">Click Here</button>to see my top <input type="text"       id="DNumber1" value=""> job duties</p>
    <p id="mduties1"></p>
```

Comment: 1) Syntax error. Missing semicolons in several places. 2) The initial value b is always a=1. So, the loop will always be iterated just once. 3) Nothing is assigned to C. Rather, the value of C is compared to the nth element of the array. Not to mention lack of error checking. Also, most web browsers have a javascript debugger that will help you identify errors, and write your script.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
function myduties1() {
    var a= document.getElementById("DNumber1").value;
    var duties1= ["Building Houses","Using Heavy Machinery","Lifting","Fixing","Working Fast"];
    var out = "";
    if (a <= duties1.length){
        var out = (duties1.slice(0,a)).join();
    }
    document.getElementById("mduties1").innerHTML =out;
}
```

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/x2axmrnc/) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!